# How do you include the javascript helper in the ErrorHanlder?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I have this custom error handler:

`class AppError extends ErrorHandler {

function error404($params) {
  $this->controller->layout = 'public';
  $this->controller->set('title','Droptor Page Not Found');
  parent::error404($params);
 }
}`

And I can't seem to use any layout that has this:
`$javascript->link('jquery',true)`

So the JS helper isn't loaded. But if I include this in the controller: `var $helpers = array('javascript');` it still doesn't work. Nor does `App::import('Helper', 'javascript');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crap, I didn't read your question.

To add a helper to your error controller, just add this line:

```
$this->controller->helpers = array('Javascript');
```

---

There are two ways to do it:

First, you can create an [app_controller](http://book.cakephp.org/view/829/The-App-Controller) to include every component and helper that you need on all your controllers.

Second, you can load the specific resources needed to your error controller. Create a file named `error.php` in your app's root (NOT webroot) with the following code:

```
<?php
class AppError extends ErrorHandler  {
    function error404($params) {
        $this->controller->helpers = array('Javascript');
        parent::error404($params);
    }
}
```

You can also set a custom title with

```
$this->controller->set('title_for_layout', "We couldn't find what you are loooking for");
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! This worked, though I had to include Html once I delcared adding in JavaScript, as overriding it removed the include for Html I assume.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you don't need to create your own handler if all you're doing is handling a common error type, such as 404. Custom error handlers are for your application specific errors.

If you want to simply change the layout of your page when you get a 404 error, this has been answered over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899130/cakephp-how-to-can-error-pages-have-its-own-layouts).

```
function beforeRender() {
    if($this->name == 'CakeError') {
        $this->layout = false;
    }
}
```

And you can cause it using the line:

```
$this->cakeError('error404');
```

Comment: Thanks - I have fixed this. But how do you include the JS helper?

Comment: Try using "Javascript" instead of "javascript" (note the case) in the line var $helpers = array('Javascript'); Let me know if that helps.