# How do you set the page title on a custom 404 page?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I have a call to a 404 page in a controller:

```
$this->set('title','Page Not Found');
$this->cakeError('error404');
```

It uses my custom 404 page, but ignores the title. The title gets set to "Error".

How do you set it?

**public.ctp** (I'm not using blank)

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8') ;?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <?php echo $html->charset('utf-8'); ?>
    <title><?php echo $title_for_layout?></title>
```

**app_controller.php**

```
function beforeRender() {
    if($this->name == 'CakeError') {
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Page Not Found');
        $this->layout = 'public';
    }
}
```

**action**

```
$this->pageTitle = 'Page Not Found';
$this->cakeError('error404');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I just answered this question in another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298445/how-do-you-include-the-javascript-helper-in-the-errorhanlder/4306062#4306062).

You'll have to create an `error.php` in your app's root with the following code:

```
<?php
class AppError extends ErrorHandler  {
    function error404($params) {
        $this->controller->set('title_for_layout', 'Your Title');
        parent::error404($params);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I got this to work! The bug in your code is title_for_layout should be title, _even_ though my layout does use $title_for_layout in the TITLE tags. If you update your answer, I will mark it correct and up vote. Thanks!

Comment: There's no need to downvote everything. It seems mean to me. At least we are trying.

Comment: Sorry! I wasn't trying to be mean. You right, I shouldn't have. It doesn't seem to let me change it though.

Answer (score 0):

Tested this, and it works:

In the **AppController**:

```
function beforeRender(){
    if ($this->name == 'CakeError') {
        $this->layout = 'blank';
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Page Not Found');
    }
}
```

In the **layout**, blank.ctp, include:

```
<title><?php echo $title_for_layout; ?> | Site Name</title>
```

In the **action**:

```
$this->cakeError('error404');
```

Comment: Could you post your code? (blank.ctp, AppController, and the action)

Answer (score 0):

Try this then

```
function beforeRender(){
    if ($this->name == 'CakeError') {
        $this->layout = 'public';
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Page Not Found');
    }
}
```

The problem with your code is that errors default to the empty layout. If you aren't using that layout then you need to specify the error layout. In the example above RabidFire has you specify the blank layout. Specify instead the layout you wish to use - in this case public.ctp/

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clear. I did update his code to the right layout, to use public. The right layout loads with the error page, so I can confirm it's working. I just can't set the page title. Any other ideas?

Comment: I get down rep for helping you with something? None of us posted bad code - I *literally* tested what I provided and it worked. Just saying - that might not be the best way to get your future questions answered.